# Django is not prepending STATIC_URL to file paths

Tags: django

For whatever reason, Django is not adding '/static/' to the urls that I'm telling it to.

Template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>Static Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <!-- <img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/> -->
        <link href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="{% static '/css/navbar-static-top.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
....
```

HTML output in Firefox and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>Static Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <!-- <img src="/static/my_app/myexample.jpg" alt="My image"/> -->
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="/css/navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
....
```

Here are my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'server_files', 'static')
```

I have tried deleting the contents of my static root directory and recalling 'collectstatic' but to no avail. Anyone know what the problem might be, or what I should be doing to try to debug this?

Comment: Paths starting with `/` are considered to be *absolute* so `/static/` is not prepended. Can you try without that: `{% static 'css/navbar-static-top.css' %}`?

Comment: @ozgur thank you for the explanation!